# Combine array by key factor

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which are obtained from a form where the user defines kind like a routing plan. This form is processes separatly and returns these two following arrays. I want to combine with the following logic:

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [route] => 1
            [origin] => zurich
            [target] => madrid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [route] => 2
            [origin] => lisbon
            [target] => dublin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [route] => 3
            [origin] => rome
            [target] => paris
        )

)

$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [route] => 2
            [checkpoint] => london
        )

)
```

Combine them by its "route" key (if set in $array2)

```
$desired = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [route] => 1
            [origin] => zurich
            [target] => madrid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [route] => 2
            [origin] => lisbon
            [target] => dublin
            [checkpoint] => london
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [route] => 3
            [origin] => rome
            [target] => paris
        )

)
```

I tryed several different array functions but without success. I think I'll have to loop through them manually but I am not sure how.

I've searched on Stackoverflow but couldn't find similar problem. But maybe because I don't know the tecnical word for this kind of operation.

Comment: is `$array1 => route` always one bigger then key?

Comment: yes. but on $array2 only routes with checkpoints are stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop the array2 first, then loop again in search for the corresponding route inside array1. If they match, just merge them:

```
foreach ($array2 as $value) {
    foreach ($array1 as &$value2) {
        if($value2['route'] == $value['route']) {
            $value2 = array_merge($value2, $value); // just join them
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, but this might do a few extraneous iterations.

Comment: @Th3Alchemist you var dumped the `$value2` :) should be `var_dump($array1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could "revert" the two arrays, by creating a structure where you map routeID to array index, for both of them: you loop over each array and build something like:

```
$revArr1 = Array
(
  '1' => 0,
  '2' => 1,
  '3' => 2
)
```

and

```
$revArr2 = Array
(
  '2' => 0
)
```

Then, you iterate over `$revArr1`'s keys and for each key you check if there is a corresponding key in `$revArr2`.
If yes, you are ready to fetch `$array2[$correspondingIndex]` which is the sub-array corresponding to the route you want to enrich in `$array1`.

It takes you 2 full iterations of `$array1` and 1 full iteration of `$array2`.
Plus, additional loops if you have remaning routes in `$array2` which did not appear in `$array1`.

There are probably more efficient algorithms to do this. Try looking at `array_filter` or `array_map`.

Answer (score 1):

Nested arrays require a double loop:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
foreach( $array2 as $checkpoint){
    if( $checkpoint['route'] === $array1[$key]['route'] ){
       $array1[$key]['checkpoint'] =  $checkpoint['checkpoint'];       
    }    
}
```

}